# is there an add-on to switch between gpu and cpu?

Tags: add-on, gpu

When rendering an animation I'd like an add-on that switches to the gpu when I'm not using the computer; i.e., no mouse or keyboard activity.  After 5 minutes of mouse/keyboard inactivity it would stop rendering the current frame with the cpu and restart using the gpu.  I prefer to do rendering with the cpu when I'm in front of the computer because with gpu rendering the mouse is jerky and slow.

If such an add-on doesn't exist, where could I suggest it?